# Run Pi-Hole, Nextcloud and Apache on the same Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-hole, nextcloud

Sorry in case this is a noob question but I am new.
I was wondering how I can install and use those three and in future maybe even more programs, while all pointing to the same IP. I managed to change ports for apache so i can access both Pi-Hole and the website, but failed to get Nextcloud running, since every request gets forwarded to the Pi-Hole's front page.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Pi-Hole is an  `DNS sinkhole` it is normal , that mean all DNS requests go to Pi-Hole. If you can contact your HTTP apache server, then it's probably one problem side Nexcloud . have you try to configure nexcloud from [here](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/general/devenv.html) ? For installation go to : `http://localhost`, if you cannot access to this url try: `http://127.0.0.1` for bypass DNS request and Pi-Hole

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using tools like docker and docker-compose.
Each container has different port. Your will be mapping ports of containers to your host to avoid problems.
I am assuming you are using raspberry pi os.

Summary:

- Install docker
- Install docker-compose
- Clone repository
- Create a file called **docker-compose.yml**
- Insert content on that file
- Run docker-compose
- Access to apache, nextcloud and pihole

**Docker and docker-compose**

for **docker** install:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

Add your user to the Docker group (Optional, to avoid using sudo):

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

If you ran the previous command, remember to log out and back in for this to take effect!

Test docker:

```
$ docker version
```

Now install **docker-compose**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev
$ sudo apt install python3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

Already you have the necessary for running the containers.

The next steps, clone a project repository to create by docker-compose the containers:

```
git clone https://github.com/SensorsIot/IOTstack.git IOTstack
cd IOTstack
```

Create a file docker-compose.yml:

```
$ touch docker-compose.yml
```

and paste the content:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  nextcloud:
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/nextcloud/html:/var/www/html

    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud
    ports:
    - "9321:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
    - nextcloud_db
    links:
    - nextcloud_db
    networks:
    - iotstack_nw
    - nextcloud_internal
    environment:
    - MYSQL_HOST=nextcloud_db
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mySQL_password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
    - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  nextcloud_db:
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mySQL_password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
    - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

    image: linuxserver/mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud_db
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/nextcloud/db:/config
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - nextcloud_internal

  mariadb:
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mySQL_password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
    - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    image: linuxserver/mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/mariadb/config:/config
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - iotstack_nw
  portainer-ce:
    container_name: portainer-ce
    image: portainer/portainer-ce
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - ./volumes/portainer-ce/data:/data
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "5053:53/udp"
    - "5053:53/tcp"
    - "9322:80"
    - "8443:443"
    environment:
    - TZ:America/Chicago
    volumes:
    - ./etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/
    - ./etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/
    dns:
    - 127.0.0.1
    - 1.1.1.1
  apacheserver:
    container_name: apache
    image: httpd:2.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "9320:80"
    - "9443:443"
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/apache/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs

networks:
  iotstack_nw: # Exposed by your host.
    # external: true
    name: IOTstack_Net
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 10.77.60.0/24
        # - gateway: 10.77.60.1

  iotstack_nw_internal: # For interservice communication. No access to outside
    name: IOTstack_Net_Internal
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 10.77.76.0/24
        # - gateway: 10.77.76.1 
  nextcloud_internal: # Network for NextCloud service
    name: IOTstack_NextCloud
    driver: bridge
    internal: true

  # default:
  #   external: true
  #   name: iotstack_nw

  # hosts_nw:
  #   driver: hosts
```

Now start docker-compose:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

You will have an output like this

```
Creating network "IOTstack_NextCloud" with driver "bridge"
Creating network "IOTstack_Net" with driver "bridge"
Creating network "iotstack_default" with the default driver
Creating pihole       ... done
Creating nextcloud_db ... done
Creating portainer-ce ... done
Creating mariadb      ... done
Creating apache       ... done
Creating nextcloud    ... done
```

If you want to see the containers running, only run:

```
$ docker ps
```

You will see a similar output like this

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                             PORTS                                                                                             NAMES
xxxxxxxxxxxx   nextcloud                "/entrypoint.sh apac…"   12 seconds ago   Up 8 seconds                       0.0.0.0:9321->80/tcp                                                                              nextcloud
yyyyyyyyyyyy   linuxserver/mariadb      "/init"                  16 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds                      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                                                                            mariadb
wwwwwwwwwwww   httpd:2.4                "httpd-foreground"       16 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds                      0.0.0.0:9320->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9443->443/tcp                                                       apache
vvvvvvvvvvvv   portainer/portainer-ce   "/portainer"             16 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds                      0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                                                    portainer-ce
nnnnnnnnnnnn   pihole/pihole:latest     "/s6-init"               16 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds (health: starting)   67/udp, 0.0.0.0:5053->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5053->53/udp, 0.0.0.0:9322->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp   pihole
ffffffffffff   linuxserver/mariadb      "/init"                  16 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds
```

At this point you can access to the different services on your browser:

```
portainer: to see containers. Need to create admin credentials to finish configuration.
http://localhost:9000 

apache. Need to create an index.html on ./volumes/apache/
http://localhost:9320 

nextcloud. Need to create admin credentials to finish configuration.
http://localhost:9321 

pihole. You can find password typing $ docker logs pihole  or access to container through  $ docker exec -ti apache bash    and inside the container run $ sudo pihole -a -p   to create a new password

http://localhost:9322/admin/
```

If containers are created but you want to eliminate them, only run

```
$ docker-compose down
```

Important!
I only tested the docker-compose file with nextcloud, portainer and mariadb on my raspberry pi 4 2gb. Apache and pihole was added and tested on desktop pc.

The apps versions running on my rpi are:

- Nextcloud 20.0.6
- 10.1.47-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
- Portainer 2.1.1

Raspberry pi:

- Linux raspberrypi 5.10.11-v7l+ #1399 SMP Thu Jan 28 12:09:48 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux

Of course you can change values of docker-compose.yml file according to your requirements.

you can find more information on :

- https://pumpingco.de/blog/setup-your-raspberry-pi-for-docker-and-docker-compose/
- https://www.sensorsiot.org/wireguard-and-nextcloud/
- https://background.sysfactory.online/index.php/2021/02/09/proxy-inverso-con-https-nextcloud-y-apache-en-raspberry-pi-4/

Comment: touch docker-compose.yml   I think you meant "nano" or "vi" from context. Nicely done and I've copied the compose file for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems too with NextCloud and Pi-Hole.
With NextCloud working, pi-Hole didn't work after installation (in any case the webserver didn't work).

After a complete installation of Pi-Hole (with `lighttpd` the webserver), I had to change pi-hole's port from `80` to `8080`

What didn't work for me:

- Add the port server configuration in a new file `/etc/lighttpd/external.conf`
- Delete `external.conf` and change port configuration in `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

What worked:

- Change port configuration in `/etc/lighttpd/lightppd.conf`
- `sudo touch /etc/lighttpd/external.conf` to create an empty `external.conf` file

I can now access the server with
`http://192.168.68.108:8080/admin/`or `http://pi.hole:8080/admin/` or `http://myPiName:8080/admin/`

I didn't see any problem between the two functions of my Pi since.

Comment: The problem with this is that the PiHole directs ad lookups to port 80, and expects a blank image or empty page to be served rather than the traffic hitting whatever else you have running on 80.